# Add a owner of a community with IBM connections Cloud API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

With the API of Connections community we can add member as described in this URL : 
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Adding_a_member_programmatically&content=apicontent

I try to add a owner not a member in a community but he always become a member even if I am posting this informations for the user :

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
    <contributor>
        <email>michel.nico@connelink.fr</email>
        <snx:userid xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">My user ID</snx:userid>
        <snx:userState xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">active</snx:userState>
        <snx:isExternal xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">false</snx:isExternal>
        <name>Michel NICO</name>
    </contributor>
    <snx:role xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" component="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/communities">owner</snx:role>
    <category term="business-owner" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>
    <category term="person" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"> </category>
    <snx:orgId xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">The ID of our cloud</snx:orgId>
</entry>
```

It always create me as a member and not as an owner.
How can we create a user with the owner role in a community ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suport send a response to me : 
No need to add so many field to add a person :

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <contributor>
        <email>mailadress</email>
    </contributor>
<snx:role xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" component="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/communities">owner</snx:role>
</entry>
```

is enouth to create a person.

But I try to add me as a owner of a community that was the problem : when the admin account try to add him, he can be member only. When you try to add someone else, you can add him as an owner.
This limitation was not described in the documentation. 
Now it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, but I think the `term=person` item is for activities and not communities, at least that what the docs show. You might remove that and see what happens. I have a feeling it's overriding the `owner` role you're trying to set.

Comment: I delete this element end it create the person. But still as a member and not the owner. Thanks for your response